# How to renice by process name?

Tags: command-line, macos

I am trying to Launch a process using NICE but this process is starting other process by itself and they are not affected by the priority of the main process ( main process has the correct nice but sub process priority is set to default)

So I am trying to renice those process while they run.
I tried

```
 renice n -p $(pidof <process name>)
```

but it is not recognised by MacOS (it is probably linux specific ?)
so how can I do that?

you can find a related discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062340/starting-process-with-nice-command-macos-leaves-the-process-priority-at-0#comment48287323_30062340

thanks.

Comment: :renice is not a command line program I don't think any begin with :  I suspect the format of that question is confusing - I have edited t to make it clearer

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it is edited

Comment: I see no need for downvotes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pgrep` instead of `pidof` on OS X. Using your example from earlier, the following should work:

```
renice n -p $(pgrep <process name>)
```

That said, a child started after the parent has had their priority changed *should* inherit the parent's priority.

Comment: Yes... well It seems that After effect command line render starts aerenderCore as a "child" process. and it is not affected by the priority of its parents.
I still have to test you code line, I'll be back!

Comment: I've been looking all over for this answer. Thanks ... six years later!

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple correct answers, here an answer let suits your train of thought.

Run this oneliner:

```
renice 10 -p $(ps -ax | grep -i [p]rocessname | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')
```

What is does:

- `renice 10`, this will make your process run with the nicety of ten, the nicer, the higher the number.
- `-p` expects the process id
- `ps -ax` lists all running processes with there name and `PID`
- `grep -i [p]rocessname` only matches the processes with 'processname', case insensitive. the brackets will prevent to match the `grep` process itself.
- `awk 'NR==1{print $1}'` will fetch the 1st instance (`NR==1`) of the first column (`$1`)

You already gave a good example of [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash).

Comment: Actually `10` is lower, `-10` is higher, a higher value lowers the process priority to make it `nice`r